# Ms Access VBA query crashing Application - returning ???? answer

Tags: mysql, ms-access, corrupt

This code has been running for 5 years with no issues and suddenly today I'm getting runtime error 13.

The code returns a string then a Double from a mysql server.

I have constructed the query in ms access as a standalone query and all data shows perfectly, however when i create a DAO recordset from the data and try and read the Double it crashes (App closes)

- I have tried Print.Debug and it auto crashes
- I have tried MSGBOX rsTrans(myField) and this shows:

> A??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

and then it freezes them closes.

query info:

```
    SELECT chemist.chemistName, reconcil.ReconChemVal, chemist.Active, reconcil.ReconZephyrVal, 
    chemist.ChemShortCode, reconbatch.ReconDate, reconbatch.ReconbatchID, chemist.BSB, chemist.AccountNumber 
    FROM 
reconbatch INNER JOIN ((chemist INNER JOIN scriptbatch ON chemist.ChemShortCode = 
    scriptbatch.chemistID) INNER JOIN (reconcil INNER JOIN scripts ON reconcil.reconcilID = 
    scripts.reconcilID) ON scriptbatch.ScrBatchID = scripts.ScrBatchID) ON reconbatch.ReconbatchID = 
    reconcil.ReconbatchID 
GROUP BY chemist.chemistName, reconcil.ReconChemVal, chemist.Active, 
    reconcil.ReconZephyrVal, chemist.ChemShortCode, reconbatch.ReconDate, reconbatch.ReconbatchID, 
    chemist.BSB, chemist.AccountNumber 
HAVING (((reconcil.ReconChemVal)>0) AND ((chemist.Active)=-1) AND 
    ((chemist.BSB) Is Not Null) AND ((chemist.AccountNumber) Is Not Null));
```

I have posted the query just to add as much info as possible. Once again, if I run this in MYSQL WORKBENCH I get a 100% correct result and no errors, all data showing as it should. If I try to read the recordset and view ReconChemVal then Access crashes!

I have now created the above query as a VIEW in MYSQL and still the data appears 100% correct in msaccess opening the view.

Once again if I try and run the code using a DAO recordset it shows the same weird text and then crashes with a runtime 13.

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
Dim test3 As DAO.Recordset

Set test3 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM reconEmails WHERE reconbatchID = 92", dbOpenDynaset)
test3.MoveLast
test3.MoveFirst

MsgBox test3.RecordCount
```

I'm wondering if some kind of windows update or something has screwed with access and ODBC?

Comment: Most probably it's the new bug in Office 365 Version 2005. Is there a DECIMAL type involved somewhere? -- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/access-crashes-since-latest-june-office-365-update/92521a6b-5f29-418f-9acb-e5e6d5e86381

Comment: amazing. thank you SO much.  I have changed all to DOUBLE

Answer (score 0):

As per ANDRE I have changed all my decimals to DOUBLES and it works again